# Can we access randomly a part of byte

Tags: c#, memory

Can we access randomly a part of byte.I mean can i access three bits of a bit randomnly without using BitArray and accessing by byte.
Is there any possibility of accessing bit from byte and if not why it is not possible to access it and is it depends on any criteria

Comment: The simpler is to use bitwise operations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation By "and-ing" with the proper power of two, you can access the different bits independently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Bitwise And (&) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator) in order to read a specific bit from a byte. I'll give some examples by using the `0b` prefix, which in C# allows you to write **binary literals** in your code.

So suppose you have the following byte value:

```
byte val =      0b10010100;   // val = 148 (in decimal)
byte testBits = 0b00000100;   // set ONLY the BITS you want to test here...

if ( val & testBits != 0 )    // bitwise and will return 0 if the bit is NOT SET.
    Console.WriteLine("The bit is set!");
else
    Console.WriteLine("The bit is not set....");
```

Here's a method for you to test any bit in a given byte, which uses the [Left-Shift operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/left-shift-operator) applied to the number 1 in order to generate a binary number which is able to be used for testing against any arbitrary bit in the given byte:

```
public static int readBit(byte val, int bitPos)
{
    if ((val & (1 << bitPos)) != 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You can use this method to print which bits are set in a given byte:

```
byte val = 0b10010100;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    int bitValue = readBit(val, i);
    Console.WriteLine($"Bit {i} = {bitValue}");
}
```

The output from the code above should be:

```
Bit 0 = 0
Bit 1 = 0
Bit 2 = 1
Bit 3 = 0
Bit 4 = 1
Bit 5 = 0
Bit 6 = 0
Bit 7 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use bit shifting

```
var bitNumber = 0;
var firstBit = (b & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0  ;
```

we can convert this to extension method

```
public static class ByteExtensions
{
    public static bool GetBit(this byte b, int bitNumber) =>
        (b & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0;

}
```

then

```
byte b = 7;
var bit0 = b.GetBit(3);
```